# "Cannot execute binary file" with alias of binary

Tags: macos, python, binary

I have installed both python3.3 and python2.6. 
I have set python3.3 to default by creating an alias named "python" in usr/bin and another one for python2.6 named "python2.6".
Now if I type in the terminal "python" python3.3 will be open but if I type "python2.6" I get "cannot execute binary file". 
I can launch the binary directly but not through the alias.
I have checked the permissions and are the same for both binaries and aliases so I don't know what to do.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you create aliases (in Finder) or symbolic links (in Terminal)? Can you execute the python2.6 binary in its installation directory directly?

Comment: Aliases using finder and yes, I can run python 2.6 from the original folder without problems.

Comment: I would recommend using symbolic links for this instead of aliases

Comment: I created a link using "ln" and it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using Finder aliases, use Terminal to create symbolic links (see `man ln` for details on usage):

```
ln -s /path/to/python3.3/binary /usr/local/bin/python
ln -s /path/to/python2.6/binary /usr/local/bin/python2.6
```

It's usually not a good idea to mess with `/usr/bin` content (will be wiped out with the next upgrade). Use `/usr/local/bin` instead and make sure it comes before `/usr/bin` in $PATH.